# Whats the quickest way to find a file in Zend Studio for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, keyboard-shortcuts, zend-studio, text-search

I want to be able to find files quickly in Zend Studio for Eclipse without routing through a tree view of dozens of folders and hundreds of files.

What I'm really after is something that filters file names as I type. Think spotlight on Mac, or the filter on the start menu in Vista.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+R (or Command+Shift+R for Mac) should work. Did Zend break it?

Comment: No, Zend didn't break it, I just never knew it was there. Thanks for that, it's gonna save me a lot of time in the coming months / years.

Comment: Not exactly the same as Spotlight. Spotlight indexes the file contents while "Open Resource" is for names only.

Comment: I think it should search in path as well on only file name.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Shift+R` in Eclipse and Zend Studio.
The equivalent in NetBeans is `Shift + Alt + O`.

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for the answer. This question was not asking for a full list of shortcuts; it's not really appropriate to link to a page on your website giving that information as a response. I am removing the link so that your post does not appear to be spam.